# Getting rid of synatax errors in the following small program

Tags: sml, ml

```
datatype inttree = Empty | Node of int * inttree * inttree

fun insert(t,i)= if t=Empty then Node(i,Empty,Empty)
 else if t=Node(j,l,r):
        if (i=j) 
                 then t 
                 else if (i < j) 
          then Node(j,insert l i,r)
           else Node(j,l,insert r i)
```

the syntax errors are

```
stdIn:8.7-19.4 Error: syntax error: deleting  ELSE ID
stdIn:25.15-25.25 Error: syntax error: deleting  FUN ID
stdIn:25.32-25.36 Error: syntax error: deleting  IF ID
```

Comment: What syntax errors do you see?

Comment: This isn't your complete program. You have to tell us where those errors *are* in your program.

Comment: i cant understand that why this program is not complete

Comment: Your error messages indicate lines 8, 19, and 25. You only posted 9 lines of code. This means that you didn't post the complete program that you tried to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly formatted, here's your function:

```
fun insert(t,i) =
    if t = Empty then
        Node(i,Empty,Empty)
    else if t = Node(j,l,r):
        if (i=j) then
            t 
        else if (i < j) then
            Node(j,insert l i,r)
        else
            Node(j,l,insert r i)
```

Do you see what's wrong? The `if t = Node(j,l,r):` has no `else` to match it. Also, it should have a `then` instead of a colon (`:`).

Comment: I am a beginner to sml.As far as i know C++ allows if without else.pls help me to correct this

Comment: SML is not C++. In SML, conditionals are *expressions*, not statements - like C++'s *ternary operator* (`? : `), and also like with the ternary operator, you can't exclude the `else` branch.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, the joy of SML error messages.

I'll sidestep your syntax errors (see Gabe's answer) and propose a different solution.

This problem is much more easily (and idiomatically) solved with *pattern matching*:

```
fun insert (Empty, i) = Node (i, Empty, Empty)
  | insert (Node (j, l, r), i) = <your code here>
```

(Apologies if the syntax is off, my SML is a bit rusty.)
I left one case for you to fill in, so as not to spoil your fun entirely.